# Loading Indicator in Status Bar iOS

Tags: ios, uistatusbar, indicator

I'm trying to figure out what the loading circle animation in the status bar is. A lot of apps, when they load data, have a spinner in the status bar to indicate that the app is loading data, but I can't figure out what its called to implement it. Can someone tell me what it is called?

If you don't know what I'm talking about, but have an iOS device, try loading a web page in Safari and look at the spinner in the status bar. Thats what I'm talking about.

Here is an screenshot I took [image: Its the spinner in the statusbar].

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

Swift 3

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

as doc'd here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623102-isnetworkactivityindicatorvisibl

Comment: Yes, it definitely is. Thank you!

Comment: `isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` was deprecated in iOS 13. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56697071/3815069

Answer (score 6):

Same as above just in Swift:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the answer to this is Swift 3, you just set the property `isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` on `UIApplication` to true.

For instance in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptons` function in the app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    return true
}
```

Which basically means:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Answer (score -5):

It is `UIActivityIndicatorView`. You can check out its documentation and learn more here: [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview)

Also, to put it on the status bar, check out this link:
[Activity Monitor Status Bar](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1972-activitymonitor-status-bar.html)

Comment: Do I have to add that to the status bar?

Comment: Yes. But how nearly every application has it, in the status bar, would I have to add it there myself, or is there a method to call in the UIApplication class methods?

Comment: Basically, I don't know how I would add it to the statusbar, since I don't know how far the connection information spans across the bar.

Comment: I don't think you can put it on the status bar

Comment: Actually maybe you can. Try checking out this link: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1972-activitymonitor-status-bar.html

Comment: Oh. Then its not the view I'm looking for. Check out my screenshot in my original post. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thats it! Can you post that as an answer? That way people can see the answer quicker.

Comment: Sorry. Do you mind answering it with this exact link as a new answer? (http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1972-activitymonitor-status-bar.html#post11466)

Comment: I have to give the correct answer to CT, since his is clearer for other viewers.

Comment: I did give you a vote, though! Thanks for your help. It was really fast and concise!