# How do you get the network progress spinner to show up in iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have an app that downloads several resources from the Internet every time it loads (such as rss feeds and images). However, even though it takes several seconds to get all of the data downloaded, the progress spinner next to the Wifi/3G symbol never appears. I assume this is supposed to show anytime a network request is being made, and many 3rd party apps have this show up (such as Facebook). I am making my request using GCD on non-UI threads, but I would still expect the spinner to show.

Are their any suggestions on how to to get the spinner to show up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the loading indicator in the top status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166712/how-to-show-the-loading-indicator-in-the-top-status-bar)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are responsible for turning the network activity indicator on and off as appropriate.  For example:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```