# How to inform user when a UIView is taking time to load?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my Application user can insert hospital information into database after login. In my case, the view where user can enter data may take some time to load. That's not an issue but I want to inform the user that something is loading ( message like 'loading' as in phpmyadmin)so that he does not get confuse with that. If somebody knows about it please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options to display a loading indicator

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

https://github.com/y0n3l/LGViewHUD

[How to use activity indicator view on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593234/how-to-use-activity-indicator-view-on-iphone)

[How to show the loading indicator in the top status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166712/how-to-show-the-loading-indicator-in-the-top-status-bar)

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the long loading time by having the view display itself immediately with the 'loading' message (in a subview). Then in `viewDidAppear`, for example, start loading the rest of what you need to display the real view. Lay out the final view and when ready, remove the 'loading' message subview.

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity Indicator as loading running,once done hide that Activity Indicator.See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010237/creating-a-custom-uiactivityindicatorview).