# When api call is being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

i got one problem i.e when api call is made(which will get much data from back end) one activity indicator will be shown.at that time i pressed the access icon (which is top of all view in iphone app entered into background state. Immediately i pressed the app and that entered into foreground state. At that time activity indicatory is struck.how to handle it . after some time app is being terminated by os.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166712/how-to-show-the-loading-indicator-in-the-top-status-bar

Comment: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/tree/master/RelatedRecordEditingSample/RelatedRecordEditingSample   in this link copy LoadingView.h and LoadingView.m into your project. It's easy to implement.