# Swift4.2 Type 'UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier' (aka 'Int') has no member 'invalid'

Tags: xcode10, ios12, swift4.2, uibackgroundtask, ios-background-mode

I'm getting a weird issue where code which works in one XCode project fails to compile in another. Both run Swift4.2.

**Why do I get "UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier has no member 'invalid' error?**

import UIKit
import Foundation

```
//Type 'UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier' (aka 'Int') has no member 'invalid'
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
```

I can jump into the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier definition and see this:
[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce with Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.

Comment: I'm seeing the behavior within two different projects open in the same version of XCode. The example from https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started works, but when carried over into my project with apple watch, it gives the error.

Comment: I have same problem on Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved using `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid` instead of `.invalid`

`var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid`

Not sure why it acts so strange. In the example from raywenderlich.com code compiles without errors.

Comment: You should file a bug report with Apple. Something’s wrong here.

Comment: I wish Apple would work on the compiler error messages, especially in the context of the ever changing Swift language,

Answer (score 2):

for Xcode 11 / swift 5.1

```
var backgroundTaskID : UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: on pasting code from one project to another I suddenly got "CIFormat (aka 'Int32') has no member 'RGBA8'. As the original post states, by jumping to the definition, I could see that 'RGBA8' was defined.

In my case, changing the Swift language version in Build Settings, as per the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520306/type-nsattributedstringkey-aka-nsstring-has-no-member-font) fixed the problem.

The error seems to be due to renaming in the Apple Frameworks that occurred as part of Swift 4.2. Changing the Swift language version to 4.2 resolved the issue.